# XMLHTTPRequest Request To Open Weather Returning Status 0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, openweathermap

Title says pretty much the problem. I've entered the URL into my address bar and it comes back fine. I feel like its something stupid I just can't see because I've been staring at it for awhile, but here's the code.

```
(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  document.getElementById("weatherButton").addEventListener('click', makeRequest);
  function makeRequest() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance!');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open("GET", "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040&APPID=xxxxxxxxx&mode=json");
    httpRequest.send();
  }
  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState != 4) {
      return;
    }
    if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
      alert(httpRequest.responseXML);
    }
    if (httpRequest.status != 200) {
      alert(httpRequest.status + ": " + httpRequest.statusText_)
      alert(httpRequest.readyState)

    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: You're also requesting JSON, but alerting responseXML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the full path:

```
httpRequest.open("GET", "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040&APPID=xxxxxxxxx&mode=json");
```

Otherwise, it looks for `[yourdomain]/api.openweathermap.org/...`.

Comment: God dammit. Thank you.